# Spring Security Salt

Tags: security, spring, salt

I'm trying to add a salt when adding a new user/pwd, but the docs seem to be missing how to do this.

Here's a basic example:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

You can see by the example that neither a custom salt or custom password encoder is used.

So, how would I wire the Salt in when adding a new user/pwd?  I'd assume it would be something along the lines of:

```
@Autowired SaltSource saltSource;
protected void foo(final CustomUser user) {
    final PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    user.setPassword(encoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(), saltSource));
}
```

However, since I am using the default salt/password encoders and I don't have a custom salt bean the autowire would fail.

Any clue how to make this work?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't autowire the `SaltSource` when adding user. The `SaltSource` is an abstraction used by Spring to provide the source of the salt for **password checking only**.

To create a properly encoded password hash You just past the salt itself to the `PasswordEncoder` - the value of `username` property, not the `SaltSource`:

```
private PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();

public User createUser(String username, String plainTextPassword) {
    User u = new User();
    u.setUsername(username);
    u.setPassword(encoder.encodePassword(plainTextPassword, username));
    getEntityManager().persist(u); // optional
    return u;
}
```

---

Moreover the autowire of `SaltSource` won't work until it's defined as an inner bean. You could define the `ReflectionSaltSource` as top level bean and pass it's ID to the `password-encoder`, i.e.:

```
<bean id="saltSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource"
    p:userPropertyToUse="username" />

<bean id="passwordEncoder" 
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" />

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"
    p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
    p:saltSource-ref="saltSource"
    p:userDetailsService-ref="userDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

And then:

```
@Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Autowired private SaltSource saltSource;

public CustomUserDetails createUser(String username, String plainTextPassword) {
    CustomUserDetails u = new CustomUserDetails();
    u.setUsername(username);
    u.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(
            plainTextPassword, saltSource.getSalt(u)));
    getEntityNamager().persist(u); // optional
    return u;
}
```

Comment: The newer code doesnt seem to work.  I get the following:   IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: I corrected the XML code - forgot the `-ref` suffix on references.

Comment: Be careful when considering the use of the username as the salt source. If the username changes, the salt will change and the user won't be able to log in since the encoded password is against the previous username used as the salt.