# Spring Security salt for custom UserDetails

Tags: spring-security, configuration, salt

I would like to add salt like:

```
PasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();
        userDetails.setPassword(encoder.encodePassword(userDetails.getPassword(),saltSource.getSalt(userDetails));
```

as far `userDetails` is instance of my custom `UserDetail` class,i obliged to cast it to this spring class:[UserDetails](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)
,but as it's logically expected i got in Runtime:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: model.UserDetails cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
```

config:

```
<beans:bean id="saultSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider>
<password-encoder hash="sha">
    <salt-source user-property="username"/>
</password-encoder>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

How can I configure **salt** correctly in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReflectionSaltSource` only works with a `UserDetails` object (I'm assuming that's where you get the class-cast exception?), so you would have to either implement `UserDetails` or create your own `SaltSource` implementation which works with your object.

However, I wouldn't use a property of the user as the salt unless you are working with a legacy system which already does this. The username is not a very good salt value. It's much better to use a random salt which is stored with the password. A good example is the BCrypt algorithm. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8521251/241990) for an example of using it with Spring Security 3.1. As explained there, BCrypt automatically generates a random salt which it stores in the same string as the hashed password.

Note that there is actually a new [`PasswordEncoder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#spring-security-crypto-passwordencoders) interface in the Spring Security 3.1 "crypto" package (in `org.springframework.security.crypto.password`). This doesn't include a salt in the [API methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html), since it assumes the salt is internally generated (as it is with the BCrypt implementation). The framework will generally accept one of these or the legacy `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder`.

Comment: @Luke, as I understand from your linked post,`BCrypt` already contains Salt.How can I configure Salt in this case? Is it configurable at all,when using `BCrypt`?There said:"This automatically generates a salt and concatenates it with the hash value in a single String"

Comment: @sergionni: notice the API change in Spring Security! In 3.0.x the [PasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/PasswordEncoder.html) uses the salt to encode password. But in 3.1.x the [PasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) doesn't use the salt. Luke's advice is for version 3.1.x **only**.

Comment: @Roadrunner, my version is 3.0.0.RC1.Thank you for hint.

Comment: @sergionni: Why RC1? RELEASE version is there for months. You should seriously consider the latest 3.0.x version: [3.0.7.RELEASE](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.7.RELEASE).

Comment: @Roadrunner ,I have one more question.I've specified 3.1.0.RELEASE in my pom file. Is salt generated by default with this construction:`userDetails.setPassword(encoder.encodePassword(userDetails.getPassword(), null));`

Comment: @sergionni: this doesn't even compile with 3.1.0.RELEASE - the method signature is:  [PasswordEncoder.encode(CharSequence)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.CharSequence))! Just do `userDetails.setPassword(encoder.encodePassword(plainTextPwd));` and this will generate a hash using a random salt. Password checking is than done by `encoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)`. Just have a look at the reference documentation / API documentation / sources.

Comment: I should have made it clearer that there is actually a new PasswordEncoder interface in 3.1 which is now preferred over the former one. I've updated the answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model.UserDetails` class must implement the **interface** `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` - it does not need to be a **class** `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`.

You can also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8068064/719633) to see how to set up a `ReflectionSaltSource` for both encoding and decoding passwords, or help You get the bigger picture to follow Luke's great tip on `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

Comment: I saw your post earlier.As I understand,the class `CustomUserDetails` in it implements spring's `UserDetails`,isn't it?The case is that,I needn't implement it for now.My custom `UserDetails` is quite tiny and it's enough.

Comment: @sergionni: This was just an example placeholder - You can use any implementation of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` in place of 'CustomUserDetails' - it may be Your own, either tiny or featureful, or the one provided with the framework `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`. The main part of my post was about configuring the `SaltSource` though.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog post about some of these details here: http://rtimothy.tumblr.com/post/26527448708/spring-3-1-security-and-salting-passwords
Luke wrote the code so he certainly knows what he's talking about, but I see a number of people including myself having a hard time groking this information, hopefully that like will help.